# Newly created users cannot log into Windows

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller, login

The manager can't log onto their account any more. We aren't doing anything fancy. They just need to log into windows.

When trying to log into windows, it gives the following error:
"there are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request"

- I tried different work stations and I got the same error.
- I deleted and re-added the user from active directory, and I got the same error.
- I created a test user, and I was not able to log on with the test user either because I got the same error.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: This sounds like a DNS problem. What are the client machines using for DNS?

Comment: Have you tried any research before asking here? There are some pretty straight forward troubleshooting advises in the top search results for the error message and none of what you wrote hints towards that you did research on your own.

Comment: @daniel Yes I searched a lot before I asked the question. Do you have a specific link that will help?

Comment: @joeqwerty Our machines use Google DNS. All the other users are able to log in but newly created users cannot.

Comment: This is in an Active Directory domain right? If so, you need to configure the clients to use your AD DNS server. The computer can't find your Domain Controller by using Google DNS. The other users are likely logging in with cached credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in an Active Directory domain right? If so, you need to configure the clients to use your AD DNS server. The computer can't find your Domain Controller by using Google DNS. The other users are likely logging in with cached credentials.

Answer (score 1):

The network settings were set to Google open DNS. I switched it so that the network settings are now taken automatically from the DHCP server.